# Transaction posted in “internal transactions” how do I add it to my wallet?

Tags: transactions, addresses, etherscan

I transferred ETH from bitbuy to my ledger without realizing ledger did not support contracts. The transaction is posted on ether scan in internal transactions. I’ve contacted bitbuy and ledger both say they can’t help me. It says it was sent to my wallet successfully but isn’t reflected in the balance is there a way to recover it ? https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9be39b1a0c565625d44c4765a34f4f1c9bf50a3daf044f58dfb7922a1f9856d5

Comment: Hi. Could you add more info? And from which address was it sent and which address that you cannot see the correct balance?

Comment: https://etherscan.io/address/0xfaC9dd35E3A27D3d228733B5Ea4A1D30762f2da1#internaltx Here’s the page for my wallets transactions,

Comment: The balance is not reflected in 0xfaC9dd35E3A27D3d228733B5Ea4A1D30762f2da1

Comment: Well, I summed all value that 0xfaC9dd35E3A27D3d228733B5Ea4A1D30762f2da1 plus the value it received in the internal transaction and it is the same that Etherscan is showing. So the value is being reflected in the balance

Comment: You’re right! Sorry I’m a little lost new to all this. I didn’t actually sum it up I just never saw it received in my ledger app. Thanks a lot

Comment: Good.  No problem. Just ask here any question you have. We are here to help.